# Popup box with related info after clicking point in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I am kind of newbie and I would like your kind help.

Imagine i have a dataframe with  information that I plot in a chart. I know that by hovering on top of the points i can have the tooltips to show specific data.

I would like however, apart from that,  to be able to actually click on those points and a pop up box (or an other/alterantive tooltip) to appear with more information regarding that point.

For example click on a point and a popup to show the "term_ID" of the point and even better that to be an href search link to Google with that term "url".

Thank you so much.

My play data looks like:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def make_google_query(name):
    return "https://www.google.com/search?" + urlencode({'q': '"{0}"'.format(name)})


data = [
    ["GO:0005874","microtubule", 0.590923058896654, -4.00372136407618, 3.93380303408685, 5.07433362293908, 0.743307611944267, 0],
    ["GO:0042555","MCM complex",0.0516392267501353,5.29409032883786,-0.438484234906433,4.01582063426207,0.736867388621876,0],
    ["GO:0005886","plasma membrane",15.5064680247866,-2.59930578712986,-4.79438349762051,6.49331205332051,0.980465972776413,4.124E-05],
    ["GO:0030173","integral component of Golgi membrane",0.0482779463204013,-0.0820996416106789,6.61844221537962,3.98659260682221,0.720783016873817,0.16417986],
    ["GO:0031083","BLOC-1 complex",0.0157955281823943,6.03044083325888,2.61728943021364,3.50147007210041,0.638408624494431,0.22740185],
    ["GO:0030532","small nuclear ribonucleoprotein complex",0.138166054523554,2.1939043417736,2.03060434260059,4.44321603416583,0.571526896999077,0.2622474],
    ["GO:0008250","oligosaccharyltransferase complex",0.0394539627330108,2.22238070210506,4.52148800747906,3.89894446686651,0.602647357590838,0.39260902]
]

columns = ["term_ID","description","frequency","plot_X","plot_Y","log_size","uniqueness","dispensability"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df['url'] = df['term_ID'].apply(make_google_query)



base = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(filled=True, fillOpacity=0.5).encode(
    y=alt.Y('plot_Y', title="Semantic Space Y"),
    x=alt.X('plot_X', title="Semantic Space X"),
    size=alt.Size('log_size', scale=alt.Scale(base=0, domain=[3.5,6], range=[1000, 7000])),
    color=alt.Color('uniqueness', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='viridis')),
    

    tooltip=[
             alt.Tooltip("description"), 
             alt.Tooltip("frequency"),
             alt.Tooltip("log_size"), 
             alt.Tooltip("uniqueness"),
             alt.Tooltip("dispensability")]
)
 


text = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('plot_Y', title="Semantic Space Y"),
    x=alt.X('plot_X', title="Semantic Space X"),
    color=alt.Color('uniqueness', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='viridis')),
    text="description"
)



(base + text ).properties(
    title="plot",
    height=600,
    width=800
).interactive()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to have two separate tooltips in Altair, but you could approximate that functionality by creating a text layer that is governed by a selection:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def make_google_query(name):
    return "https://www.google.com/search?" + urlencode({'q': '"{0}"'.format(name)})


data = [
    ["GO:0005874","microtubule", 0.590923058896654, -4.00372136407618, 3.93380303408685, 5.07433362293908, 0.743307611944267, 0],
    ["GO:0042555","MCM complex",0.0516392267501353,5.29409032883786,-0.438484234906433,4.01582063426207,0.736867388621876,0],
    ["GO:0005886","plasma membrane",15.5064680247866,-2.59930578712986,-4.79438349762051,6.49331205332051,0.980465972776413,4.124E-05],
    ["GO:0030173","integral component of Golgi membrane",0.0482779463204013,-0.0820996416106789,6.61844221537962,3.98659260682221,0.720783016873817,0.16417986],
    ["GO:0031083","BLOC-1 complex",0.0157955281823943,6.03044083325888,2.61728943021364,3.50147007210041,0.638408624494431,0.22740185],
    ["GO:0030532","small nuclear ribonucleoprotein complex",0.138166054523554,2.1939043417736,2.03060434260059,4.44321603416583,0.571526896999077,0.2622474],
    ["GO:0008250","oligosaccharyltransferase complex",0.0394539627330108,2.22238070210506,4.52148800747906,3.89894446686651,0.602647357590838,0.39260902]
]

columns = ["term_ID","description","frequency","plot_X","plot_Y","log_size","uniqueness","dispensability"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df['url'] = df['term_ID'].apply(make_google_query)

selection = alt.selection_single(empty='none')

base = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(filled=True, fillOpacity=0.5).encode(
    y=alt.Y('plot_Y', title="Semantic Space Y"),
    x=alt.X('plot_X', title="Semantic Space X"),
    size=alt.Size('log_size', scale=alt.Scale(base=0, domain=[3.5,6], range=[1000, 7000])),
    color=alt.Color('uniqueness', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='viridis')),
    

    tooltip=[
             alt.Tooltip("description"), 
             alt.Tooltip("frequency"),
             alt.Tooltip("log_size"), 
             alt.Tooltip("uniqueness"),
             alt.Tooltip("dispensability")]
).add_selection(
    selection
)
 

df['long_description'] = (
    'description: ' + df['description']
    + '\nuniqueness: ' + df['uniqueness'].astype(str)
).str.split('\n') # Create a list to split into multiple lines in the chart

text = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('plot_Y', title="Semantic Space Y"),
    x=alt.X('plot_X', title="Semantic Space X"),
    color=alt.Color('uniqueness', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='viridis')),
    text="long_description"
).transform_filter(
    selection
)

(base + text ).properties(
    title="plot",
    height=600,
    width=800
).interactive()
```

The "mark_text tooltip" is only shown when clicking the points:

[image]